# Alsa conf different rate for playback and capture

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

For functionality reasons, I need to configure different rates for playback and recording.
For capture I need force a rate of 16000 but for playblack I want to keep the default.

I use plugin asym to connect capture and playback parts.
If I use individually aplay or arecord it works correctly but simultaneously I get errors and it does not work.

Would it be correct to use different frequencies for playback and capture for the same card?

```
/etc/asound.conf

pcm.!default {

        type asym

        playback.pcm {
                type hw
                card 0
                device 0
        }

        capture.pcm {
                type plug
                slave {
                        pcm {
                                type hw
                                card 0
                                device 0
                                rate 16000
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Does your hardware, whatever it is, even support different rates for playback and capture?

Comment: Yes, supports 8-kHz to 192-kHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many devices require symmetric configurations of capture and playback. This is defined in the codec itself by setting the [symmetric_rates](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/06f409d76f1d382167eb1cadde2e23a73272865d) variable.

In my case my codec forces symmetry so I can't have different capture and playback rates